# How long can a URL be? Before bad for SEO

Tags: seo, accessibility

How long can a URL be? Before bad for SEO

Comment: How short can it be and still convey all information needed?

Comment: any URL should be as short as possible, but not shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your URLs as short as possible whilst supplying the most possible relevant information.

Take stackoverflow.com as a good example. Title of the 'article' along with an ID (for optimized database searching). Best of both worlds, and very short.

Search Engines give more points the file path part of the URL than to the query string part (behind the question mark)

I doubt search engines have a maximum length limit. But a URL should never need to be very long.

Comment: but SO converts every question into url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779635/if-i-have-same-navigation-on-2-places-in-every-page-one-is-in-dropdown-and-agai like this . is it good?

Comment: @Jitendra: The example you pointed to tells us that SO strips it to 115 chars (not including `http://` )

Answer (score 0):

You should not think in terms of hard limit. Google's algo tend to give more power the fewer words there are. The more words you add the more you dilute that power.